unknown B-movie with treasure seekers, a curse and nerdy guy wielding umbrella
I want to say this sci-fi/fantasy movie was made somewhere between mid 1990s-2009s. It was in color and nothing in the manner of speech, plot or props or special effects made me think before this time period. 
I watched it on DVD that we rented from Block Buster movie store. It only came in English and I think it was a B-movie. I want to call it a B movie because I remember no advertising for it at all and I also I think i remember special effects not being too high quality. I don't remember the actors and actresses being recognizable big name types.  I also don't remember this movie having very many extras. Don't remember a lot of it. 
A group of college age kids are in a desert area for vacation or possibly searching for a treasure or artifact. There are at least 2 men and 2 women in this group. I remember the majority of this movie taking place in the desert and they are camping or wandered on this particular spot. For some reason I want to say it's in North America.
The women and the men dress like it's the late 1800s-early 1900s. I say this because I remember the ladies being in long sleeved dresses with petty coats, parasol and button boots from that time. I also think the men were in long sleeved shirts, coats and possibly bow ties even though the were in a hot temperature area. I think they are scientists or archaeologists and the ladies are scientists or archaeologists too. Or perhaps they just really enjoy archeology. They either stumble on an artifact or that's what they are specifically there for. One of the ladies is in love with one of the tough guy characters and he is a jerk. 
One of the guys is considered a nerdy screw-up. This guy looks similar to the guy who plays the main character in the TV show House but with glasses. This character is also in love with the lady who is in love with the jerk but unfortunately she doesn't seem to find the nerdy guy interesting. He has some sort of falling out with the group and wanders off. 
Meanwhile a curse or trouble comes to light. I think i remember there being a step pyramid like those in Mexico. I think there was also some sort of monster that they woke up and it begins to attack them. The nerdy guy swoops in at the nick of time and wards a creature off with his umbrella or somehow saves the day. I distinctly remember him having an umbrella or a parasol near the end. 

Welcome to the community. In terms of plot, that's not a lot to go on. Anything else for plot details? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Thank you! I am new to this place. I apologize after viewing other peoples questions and I saw what you were saying. I edited my post and tried to add as much as I could to it. I do really like this site so far :) especially how helpful people are!

Brought to mind My Science Project from 1985 (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089652/), but I haven't seen it in years, so that might just be an impression.

That isn't it but it does look interesting. Thank you!

I really want to say that you're probably mixing up two movies, and one of them is most likely the first part of The Mummy (1999) starring Brendan Fraser, Rachel Weisz, John Hannah, and Kevin J. O'Connor.
During the movie they discover the Book of the Dead and accidentally unleash the mummy Imhotep.  John Hannah plays Jonathan Carnahan, who is a nerdy screw-up in the movie.
